# ActiveXObject error when running from HTML app vs. Flex app

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, activex

In my web-based Flex app I make an external interface call to this method:

```
var arr:Array = ExternalInterface.call("getClientData", "");
```

Here is the method in my HTML page:

```
function getClientData( keys ) {
try {
    mySearchIntegration = new ActiveXObject( "pkg.myView.ExternalIntegration.getData" );
    var myObj = "";
    var cust = "";
    var custID = "";
    var custEMAIL = "";
    var custNAME = "";
    myObj = mySearchIntegration.GetData("44277F-XUI18");

}
catch (e) {

}
```

}

The function returns data.

Now, if I I try invoking the same function directly from HTML app (my JSP page on a non-IE browser), I get the following error: "ActiveXObject not defined".

Now, that makes sense to me because ActiveXObject is only supported by IE.

So, why does it work when running out of a Flex app (in a non-IE web browser) but I get the error running it as a web app from my JSP page?

Comment: It doesn't work in a non-IE browser if I access a flex object or not. It's just that I'm stubbing out data and not throwing any errors.

Answer (score 0):

My assumption wasn't correct, it doesn't work in a non-IE browser even if I have a Flex object embedded in the page.

The problem was the way I was stubbing my method out; the Flex app/External Interface connection didn't throw an error (even if there was one), and the HTML/JSP approach always did.